# WebAPI2 AuthorizeAttribute IsAuthenticated always null

Tags: authorization, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to implement CustomAuthorization via IsAuthorized method of AuthorizeAttribute.

Assumption here is by this time user would have been Authenticated and i can retriev userName and other Claims that were assigned to user during authentication. I am using Bearer Authentication.

But when i check for actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated it is always returning false.

How do i access who the user is and any claims that were assigned to him during authentication in this method?

Here is the code that i am referring to, this is not the full blown implementation, incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always false.

```
 public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {

            IPrincipal incomingPrincipal = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal;


            if (!incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return false;
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Principal is authenticated at the start of IsAuthorized in CustomAuthorizationFilterAttribute: {0}", incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated));

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you write your own AuthenticationFilter? You have to set the "Principal" to the Http-Context. Otherwise you can't access the information. Could you post your code?

Have a look here.
[Authentication Filters in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters)